# How to convert UNC to local path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, filesystems

I'm looking for a method to get corresponding local path for a given UNC path. Microsoft provides a small library [CheckLCL](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;148391&x=4&y=15) for this purpose. This library is not supported on all Windows versions. Does anybody know any open source method for this?

There is also MAPI function [ScLocalPathFromUNC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842520.aspx), but am not sure if it works on all platforms.

Comment: It looks like the library is no longer supported because its security model is fundamentally flawed. It bypasses share security. In that case, you wouldn't be able to get a new version at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some googling and digging in MSDN i have the following solution:

```
#include <Crtdbg.h>    // for debug stuff
#include "Winnetwk.h"  // for WNetGetUniversalName()
#include "Lm.h"        // for NetShareGetInfo()
#include "pystring.h"  // from http://code.google.com/p/pystring

#pragma comment( lib, "Mpr.lib" )       // for WNetGetUniversalName()
#pragma comment( lib, "Netapi32.lib" )  // for NetShareGetInfo()

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// converts x:\\folder -> \\\\server\\share\\folder
bool ConvertLocalPathToUNC(const char* szFilePath, std::string& strUNC)
{
  // get size of the remote name buffer
  DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
  char szBuff[2];
  if (::WNetGetUniversalName(szFilePath, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, szBuff, &dwBufferSize) == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
  {
    // get remote name of the share
    char* buf = new char[dwBufferSize];
    UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO* puni = (UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO*) buf;

    if (::WNetGetUniversalName(szFilePath, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, buf, &dwBufferSize) == NO_ERROR)
    {
      strUNC = puni->lpUniversalName;
      delete [] buf;
      return true;
    }
    delete [] buf;
  }

  return false;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// converts \\\\server\\share\\folder -> x:\\folder
bool ConvertUNCToLocalPath(const char* szUNC, std::string& strLocalPath)
{
  // get share name from UNC
  std::string strUNC(szUNC);
  std::vector< std::string > vecTokens;
  pystring::split(strUNC, vecTokens, _T("\\"));

  if (vecTokens.size() < 4)
    return false;

  // we need wchar for NetShareGetInfo()
  std::wstring strShare(vecTokens[3].length(), L' ');
  std::copy(vecTokens[3].begin(), vecTokens[3].end(), strShare.begin());

  PSHARE_INFO_502  BufPtr;
  NET_API_STATUS   res;
  if ((res = NetShareGetInfo(NULL, const_cast<LPWSTR>(strShare.c_str()), 502, (LPBYTE*) &BufPtr)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    // print the retrieved data.
    _RPTF3(_CRT_WARN, _T("%ls\t%ls\t%u\n"), BufPtr->shi502_netname, BufPtr->shi502_path, BufPtr->shi502_current_uses);

    std::wstring strPath(BufPtr->shi502_path);
    strLocalPath.assign(strPath.begin(), strPath.end());

    // build local path
    for (size_t i = 4; i < vecTokens.size(); ++i)
    {
      if (!pystring::endswith(strLocalPath, _T("\\")))
        strLocalPath += _T("\\");
      strLocalPath += vecTokens[i];
    }

    // Validate the value of the shi502_security_descriptor member.
    if (IsValidSecurityDescriptor(BufPtr->shi502_security_descriptor))
      _RPTF0(_CRT_WARN, _T("It has a valid Security Descriptor.\n"));
    else
      _RPTF0(_CRT_WARN, _T("It does not have a valid Security Descriptor.\n"));

    // Free the allocated memory.
    NetApiBufferFree(BufPtr);
  }
  else
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The System.Uri class may be some help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

It is similar to UNC and has a `IsUNC()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! If you are interested, i have the solution now.